# Page loads back to index page after refresh

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have created a website with multiple pages and pagination but when I am on `page2` and refresh, It goes back to the `index.php` page. Is there something to do with `session storage` or `cookies` in this case. Any solution so that it will stay on the same page even after refreshing it.

Edit:

so this is the pagination script  and all other content is also in the same page

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    var show_per_page = 9; 

    var number_of_items = $('#content').children().size();

    var number_of_pages = Math.ceil(number_of_items/show_per_page);


    $('#current_page').val(0);
    $('#show_per_page').val(show_per_page);


    var navigation_html = '<a class="previous_link" href="javascript:previous();">Prev</a>';
    var current_link = 0;
    while(number_of_pages > current_link){
        navigation_html += '<a class="page_link" href="javascript:go_to_page(' + current_link +')" longdesc="' + current_link +'">'+ (current_link + 1) +'</a>';
        current_link++;
    }
    navigation_html += '<a class="next_link" href="javascript:next();">Next</a>';

    $('#page_navigation').html(navigation_html);


    $('#page_navigation .index.php:first').addClass('active_page');


    $('#content').children().css('display', 'none');


    $('#content').children().slice(0, show_per_page).css('display', 'block');

});

function previous(){

    new_page = parseInt($('#current_page').val()) - 1;

    if($('.active_page').prev('.page_link').length==true){
        go_to_page(new_page);
    }

}

function next(){
    new_page = parseInt($('#current_page').val()) + 1;
    if($('.active_page').next('.page_link').length==true){
        go_to_page(new_page);
    }

}
function go_to_page(page_num){
    var show_per_page = parseInt($('#show_per_page').val());

    start_from = page_num * show_per_page;

    end_on = start_from + show_per_page;

    $('#content').children().css('display', 'none').slice(start_from, end_on).css('display', 'block');

    $('.page_link[longdesc=' + page_num +']').addClass('index.php').siblings('.page2.php').removeClass('active_page');
        $('#current_page').val(page_num);
}
  </script>
```

Comment: Please take a look at the [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, especially the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page it links to. We can't actually help you if you don't show us any code.

Comment: Show us the code which redirects the user to `page2`.

Comment: it basically takes you to the default url after refreshing, it will be easier to understand if you post the code as well

Comment: What's the PHP doing? Is that doing any redirects at all?

Comment: that is just a script for pagination in my index.php file

Answer (score 0):

Whenever any page is changed, you can add new page link in local storage.

```
window.localStorage.setItem('page', 'home.php');
```

When you refresh page, you need to check if there is any value for page in local storage.

```
var startPage = window.localStorage.getItem('page');

if (startPage) {
    window.location.replace(startPage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
so this is the pagination script  and all other content is also in the same page 

 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    var show_per_page = 9; 

    var number_of_items = $('#content').children().size();

    var number_of_pages = Math.ceil(number_of_items/show_per_page);


    $('#current_page').val(0);
    $('#show_per_page').val(show_per_page);


    var navigation_html = '<a class="previous_link" href="javascript:previous();">Prev</a>';
    var current_link = 0;
    while(number_of_pages > current_link){
        navigation_html += '<a class="page_link" href="javascript:go_to_page(' + current_link +')" longdesc="' + current_link +'">'+ (current_link + 1) +'</a>';
        current_link++;
    }
    navigation_html += '<a class="next_link" href="javascript:next();">Next</a>';

    $('#page_navigation').html(navigation_html);


    $('#page_navigation .index.php:first').addClass('active_page');


    $('#content').children().css('display', 'none');


    $('#content').children().slice(0, show_per_page).css('display', 'block');

});

function previous(){

    new_page = parseInt($('#current_page').val()) - 1;

    if($('.active_page').prev('.page_link').length==true){
        go_to_page(new_page);
    }

}

function next(){
    new_page = parseInt($('#current_page').val()) + 1;
    if($('.active_page').next('.page_link').length==true){
        go_to_page(new_page);
    }

}
function go_to_page(page_num){
    var show_per_page = parseInt($('#show_per_page').val());

    start_from = page_num * show_per_page;

    end_on = start_from + show_per_page;

    $('#content').children().css('display', 'none').slice(start_from, end_on).css('display', 'block');

    $('.page_link[longdesc=' + page_num +']').addClass('index.php').siblings('.page2.php').removeClass('active_page');
        $('#current_page').val(page_num);
}
  </script>
```